# Spring lazy initialization in configuration with constructor

Tags: java, spring, lazy-initialization

I have a component

```
@Component
public class ExpenseCalculator {
    @Autowired
    private TaxService taxService;

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService employeeService;

    @Autowired
    @Lazy
    private PurchaseService purchaseService;
}
```

Here `PurchaseService` is initialized only when any part of the code that uses `purchaseService` is invoked (?).

Now I have to move`ExpenseCalculator` a configuration class (it doesn't have `@Component` annotation)

```
@Configuration
public class ExpenseConfig {
    @Bean
    @Lazy
    public ExpenseCalculator getExpenseCalculator(
        TaxService taxService, 
        EmployeeService employeeService,
        PurchaseService purchaseService
    ) {
        return new ExpenseCalculator(taxService, employeeService, purchaseService);
    }
}
```

But `purchaseService` is no more a `@Lazy` component when ever `ExpenseCalculator` is initialized, `purchaseService` get initialized.

Is there any way to get lazy initialization of `purchaseService` using `configuration`?

Comment: Annotate the method argument in the configuration with `@Lazy` not the `@Bean` method.

Answer (score 2):

You must annotate your `PurchaseService` with `@Lazy` in both places - where you create them and when you autowire them.

See the [A Quick Guide to the Spring @Lazy Annotation](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-lazy-annotation) post, in the [2.2. With @Autowired](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-lazy-annotation#2-with-autowired) section exists the comment:

> **Note, that the @Lazy is mandatory in both places.**